# Google Cloud Messaging, "App Engine Java Servlet Module"

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, jar

I've been following [this Google Cloud example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld#app-engine-java-servlet-module-template) closely (though I have both the latest versions of Java and Android Studio installed) and continue to get this error in section 2.1:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Same project structure. I'm running Windows 10.
My best guess tells me that some .jar files are not compiling. I've tried commenting out sections on the dependencies in gradle, but that's not working.
I've included the auto-generated build.gradle, here:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.packtpub.googleclouddemo"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

`